# Add Config Transforms is not displaying, why?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web.config-transform

I don't know if this is an environmental issue or something; however, I have been in Configuration Manager and I have added a new "Test" and "Release", now those appear along with Debug. I went to my Web.config and right clicked and I am not seeing the "Add Config Transforms". 
My end goal is to change the  based on what environment I am publishing to. 
What are my options to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the project a Web Site? The web.config transforms seem to be only available for Web Application, but not for Web Site projects. Please reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd547590(v=vs.100).aspx#deployment

Comment: this is resolved, I had to convert to a web application