# Can't add config transforms

Tags: asp.net, config

I have [created a build configuration](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings) but the "Add Config transforms" option doesn't show up for me. I've tried currently being on that build configuration or not. I've tried to add the file manually, but then it doesn't stack with the original Web.config file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install "Configuration Transform" extension. And this option will show up.

**Tools** -> **Extension and updates...** -> (select "**Online**" and type "transform" into search box)

Comment: Thanks, I never would have considered an extension and I did find and install it. However, the option still does not appear. Also the file is not created when the project is started, in either the new configuration or an old. I don't have another file with the same name potentially blocking it's creation. Tried in both 2013 and 2015 no improvement. But I have another project where it does work! So there's still something missing.

Comment: It seems that this is only supported for web apps, not web sites. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790603/add-config-transforms-is-not-displaying-why it fully works now.

Comment: This used to be a native VS feature, not requiring an extension.  I guess only third party options are available now?

Comment: This feature is only for web projects. Because it uses web dll to transform config. You can manually run this dll, without any extensions (usefull for teamcity, for example). Also, you can manually add sub-configuration without any transform.

Comment: Why this is not there by default is criminal